# How to render the JSX that is passed as a child in React?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic

Is there a way for a react component to have dynamic content? Something along these lines,

```js
function Div(){return(<div style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}></div>)
```

and then to use it in App.js like this

```
<Div><p>ex</p></Div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use the `children` prop:

```
function Div({ children }){ 
 return (<div style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}>{children}</div>)
}
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-fire-s1jou) demonstrating different ways

Comment: Wouldn't you have to do <Div children="<p>something</p>" though? I'm wondering about just plain wrapping it

Comment: @cabbagedude You can also pass like that. Either way works.

Comment: If you use both (prop and wrapping), the nested content takes preference.